# How do you render external markdown files in Sveltekit?

Tags: markdown, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a personal website with Sveltekit and would like to include my GitHub profile README.md as a component inside a page. I've tried mdsvex and others but they only seem to process markdown already written in local files.

For example I'd like to include something like this:

```html
<script>
    import Markdown from 'some-library'
</script>

<Markdown src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myprofile/myprofile/main/README.md'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of getting the file contents, which you can easily do using `fetch`. If you get the data from somewhere that does not allow cross-origin requests, you will have to get the data server-side, though GitHub appears to allow such requests.

E.g.

```html
<script>
    import { marked } from 'marked';
    const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sveltejs/kit/master/README.md';
</script>

{#await fetch(url).then(r => r.text()) then text}
    {@html marked(text)}
{/await}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/746b9388d92d4187bba2762c61fae796?version=3.52.0)

You will want to put an XSS sanitizer in there, in case the Markdown library does not strip dangerous output.